# Force Retrofit2 onFailure()

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to debug some code in onFailure method of Retrofit2. That method is called when device lost internet connection while making the request, and that occurs in a random basics in my wifi. Switching off the device's connection will not work, since I check the connection before the request is done.

How could I fake the request so onFailure() gets called?

Comment: call.cancel to call onFailure

Comment: Yeah, I thought that before, but where should I cancel it?

Comment: put random url that leads to onFailure method.

Comment: you can use handler to delay some sec. or make some button